# OpenCV - HoughCircles gives 5-10% inaccuracy

Tags: opencv, emgucv, image-recognition, opencv3.1

Using EmguCV with C#, MS VS 2015. Goal is to recognise black circles on white sheet (with some dust). Circles radiuses is about 80 pixels, no adjoining circles.

Given `IntPtr ptrImg` contains `byte[]` with grayscale image (8 bits per sample, one channel).

There's a code for circles detection:

```
Mat mat = new Mat(height, width, DepthType.Cv8U, 1, ptrImg, width);

CvInvoke.FastNlMeansDenoising(mat, mat, 20);

return CvInvoke.HoughCircles(mat, HoughType.Gradient, 2.0, 120.0, 90, 60, 60, 100);
```

In fact, some of the circles are detected ok, but some others have a glitch - detected radius differs from real radius for about 5-7 pixels; detected boundary coincides real boundary at one side and misses at the opposite side.

[image: top-right - radius more than real; bottol-left - radius less than real]

What do I wrong? Maybe, I have to play with dp, param1, param2? What have I to do with them?

P.S. If I remove denoising, but add binarization by threshold, the situation isn't better:
[image]

Comment: It could be that the denoising is actually modifying slightly the circle? can you post the image after the denoising?

Comment: When I comment off the denoising line, the result is about the same. Top-right circle becomes better, but medium-bottom becames worse.

Comment: Maybe a manual denoising can be better, for example you can try to threshold like less than 5 is black and the rest white and then maybe an erode/dilate operation to have only the black circles

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it too. As for now, I simply perform result rectification by myself, but I still hope there's a way to reduce the payload.

Comment: If your images really look like that, just do a binary threshold for everything that is less than the colour of the circle. Thatll turn everything else to solid white and make the image processing a doddle

Comment: also if you provide input images you might find people having a go and showing you their results.

Comment: Binary threshold doesn't make the things better. I've added the picture with threshold to the post.